# How to parse and read data from the html in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

The html content I getting from a request is below,

```
 <meta id="state" content="{&quot;config&quot;: {&quot;application_string_templates&quot;: {&quot;cta.button&quot;: &quot;Book Appointment&quot;, &quot;facet.insurance_plans.typeahead.placeholder&quot;: &quot;Choose Insurance Accepted&quot;, &quot;facet.languages.language.typeahead.placeholder&quot;: &quot;Choose Language&quot;, &quot;facet.location.placeholder&quot;: &quot;City, State (e.g. Atlanta, GA) or Zip&quot;, &quot;facet.name.accepting_new_patients&quot;: &quot;Accepting New Patients&quot;, &quot;facet.name.age_groups_seen.name&quot;: &quot;Age Groups Seen&quot;, &quot;facet.name.direct_book_capable&quot;: &quot;Book Online&quot;, &quot;facet.name.gender&quot;: &quot;Provider Gender&quot;, &quot;facet.name.insurance_plans&quot;: &quot;Insurance Accepted&quot;, &quot;facet.name.is_primary_care&quot;: &quot;Primary Care&quot;, &quot;facet.name.is_specialty_care&quot;: &quot;Specialty Care&quot;, &quot;facet.name.languages.language&quot;: &quot;Language&quot;}">
```

Here I want to get the data of attribute content.
Here is my code,

```
function parseData(html){
 const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
 const dom = new JSDOM(html);
 const $ = (require('jquery'))(dom.window);
 //let's start extracting the data
 console.log($("#state"));
}
```

When I tried to get it by id 'state',this is the output I got,

```
jQuery { '0': HTMLMetaElement {}, length: 1 }
```

Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Typo at the end of your element...

Comment: The `<meta>` you have don't seems to contain valid JSON. I don't see any closing curly brace `}`.

Comment: Modified  ......

Comment: It's still not really a valid JSON as the braces count don't match but you can get the content value with `$("#state").attr("content")`.